# How is disk memory being used up in Google Colab?

Tags: memory, google-colaboratory

The moment I mount my Google Drive into Google Colab most of the disk memory gets used up.
I mount by running the following cell

```
# Mount Google Drive (Run this in Google Colab environment)
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Once mounted, without saving any model, there is only 29 GB left out of the the 68.4 GB provided. What would be taking up so much memory? Or, how do I check what is taking up the memory?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This should not happen. mine started at 69.46 GB and remained the same.
Maybe GPU resource is being allocated which does reduce the disk size. Mine was reduced to 29.83 GB.

In this case, gpu can be disabled by going to **Edit -> notebook settings -> under hardware acceleration** which should be on **none**, to disable GPU.

And to check for disk usage

enter command `!du /path/to/your/folder -h`

you can search for the entire machine with this command `!du / -h` which scans the entire virtual machine.